# dynamic polymorphism in c++ and function overloading

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Does function overloading with polymorph object work in C++. I want to achieve a behaiviour similar to the code below.

Edit:
I want setInput to have different functionality for each derived class. 
That `task.setInput(derived2)` calls `setInput(BaseClass* object)`, destroys it for me. That allow miss using the api. So I think I have to switch functionality in the method. I guess using `dynamic_cast` will do it? Thx a lot. :-)

```
class BaseClass { virtual void xy() .. }
class Derived1Class : BaseClass { .. } 
class Derived2Class : BaseClass { .. } 
class Derived3Class : Derived2Class { .. } 

class Task {
    void setInput(BaseClass* object);
    void setInput(Derived1Class* object);
    void setInput(Derived2Class* object);
    void setInput(Derived3Class* object);
}

main() {
   BaseClass* base = new BaseClass();
   Derived1Class* derived1 = new Derived1Class();
   BaseClass* derived2 = new Derived2Class();
   Derived2Class* derived3 = new Derived3Class();
   Task* task =  new Task();
   task.setInput(base);
   task.setInput(derived1);
   task.setInput(derived2);
   task.setInput(derived3);
}
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by "work", which overload do you expect `task.setInput(derived2)` to call?

Comment: Do you mean multiple dispatch? (This means polymorphism based on all arguments, not just `this`.)

Comment: I guess you want `task.setInput(derived2)` to call the overload with `Derived2Class*` argument, which is **not** the case here. Polymorphism in C++ only works for the **subject** (that is the object on which the function is called), not for the arguments. As @TheodorosChatzigiannakis mentions, this requires a technique known as "multiple dispatch", which most OOP languages (like C++, also Java for another example) don't support out of the box but can be "emulated" using the Visitor design pattern. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch

Comment: If you do need multiple dispatch, after all, look into the visitor pattern.

Comment: @leemes I don't really see how the visitor design pattern would help? Maybe I could do a backcall ´virtual void callSetInput(Task* task)´ to Base/Derived class calling ´setInput(this)´ so also ´task.setInput(derived2);´ would dispatch to the right function. Maybe this is basic principle of visitor pattern?

Comment: @GiCo The visitor pattern is essentially a workaround for the fact that some languages (like C++ and Java) don't support multiple dispatch. It isn't immediately obvious (at least, it wasn't obvious to me) that this pattern solves that problem until you actually use it...

Comment: @GiCo ...To use it, make `Task` a visitor, make the hierarchy of `BaseClass` accept the visitor (in a virtual method), then override that method in each individual class to call the correct overload of the visitor, with `this` as the argument. The overload called from each individual override is still selected statically - but the override itself (that essentially maps to each individual overload) is selected dynamically.

Comment: @Theodoros thanks. Ok seems I have seen the visitor in the past as a special pattern for traversal, but it can "also/simply" be used to to call a function with the "downcasted" type of an object. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers say, the function calls will be:

```
void setInput(BaseClass* object);         // F0
void setInput(Derived1Class* object);     // F1
void setInput(Derived2Class* object);     // F2
void setInput(Derived3Class* object);     // F3

task.setInput(base);                      // calls F0        
task.setInput(derived1);                  // calls F1
task.setInput(derived2);                  // calls F0
task.setInput(derived3);                  // calls F2
```

So the function called depends on the type of the pointer and not the type of the object it points at (no overriding polymorphism on function arguments).

There is polymorphism available which we can't see in this example because there is a definition of setInput () for each pointer type.
This is function overloading which will allow derived pointers to be matched 
with base pointers eg
if the only function defined was

void setInput(BaseClass* object);         // F0

then all the following calls would still compile and call FO:

```
task.setInput(base);                      // would call F0        
task.setInput(derived1);                  // would call F0
task.setInput(derived2);                  // would call F0
task.setInput(derived3);                  // would call F0
```

The compiler will favor matching exact types before converting from
dervied to base type, when working out which function to call.

Answer (score 6):

Function overloading is done at compile time based on the static type of the argument, not on the dynamic run-time type. So something like:

```
BaseClass* derived2 = new Derived2Class();
task.setInput(derived2);
```

will call the `setInput` overload taking a `BaseClass*` *not* a `Derived2Class*`.

So the answer depends on what behaviour you were expecting but I'm guessing the answer is **no**.

Comment: Thx. Yes seems that isn't possible in the way I want to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are asking is whether a function parameter obeys polymorphism. It does indeed. A derived class pointer can be implicitly converted to a base class pointer. So having one setInput should suffice.

```
class Task {
    void setInput(BaseClass* object);
}
```

In case you want to have different functionality base on the specific derived class, then you can use overload the function setInput to accept the derived class pointer. In this case when setInput function is called, the variant that best matches the static type of the parameter is used.

But in case you need to overload setInput in this manner, then I would first try to make setInput a member of Base class/ Derived class themselves.

Comment: yes, I possibly missed the dynamic keyword in title and just read the body.

Comment: Thx. Making setInput a member of Base/Derived class doesn't make sence, because I want to work on the private fields of task.